# Is there a way to use getResourceAsStream method to read a json file present in data directory path?

Tags: java, android, file, inputstream, fileinputstream

I have a file present in data directory path like this: `/data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/files/data/en-US/ProjectStrings.json`.

This is what I am using to get the input stream:

```
InputStream ins = ProjectManager.class.getResourceAsStream("/data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/files/data/en-US/").
```

Here ins is coming as null.

Maybe the path that I am giving to getResourceAsStream is not correct. Please suggest what should the relative path that I should provide to this api to read ProjectStrings.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `Class.getResourceAsStream(…)` will only work for resources present on the application‘s classpath.

To get a stream for a file at an arbitrary filesystem location, use a FileInputStream:

```
try (var fis = new FileInputStream(pathToYourFile)) { … }
```